# Solving 5th order equation

Tags: polynomials

How do you solve $x^5-3x^4+3x^3-x^2=0$?

I want to solve this equation in the shortest and quickest way possible. How can I go about doing so?

Comment: It is $$x^2(x-1)^3$$

Comment: how did you get the result? can you show the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.\begin{split}
x^5-3x^4+3x^3-x^2 & = x^2(x^3-3x^2+3x-1)  
\end{split}

Once you are here, either  you can identify it if you know the cube formulas for $a+b/a-b$, or use the rational root theorem , followed by further division and factorization. This will tell you that:
$$
x^3-3x^2+3x-1 = (x-1)^3
$$
Hence, the answer is $x^2(x-1)^3$. Equating this to $0$ would give you two roots, $0$ (of multiplicity $2$) and $1$ (of multiplicity $3$).